# IDA overwrite String

Tags: ida

I have a string in IDA

[IDA string view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMFy8.png)

that I want to change to "Welcomd" just for a test. How can I overwrite the string. Changing the hex editor does not work for me.

Answer (score 3):

Select the string, and then go to Edit -> Patch Program -> Change Byte

If you're changing "Welcomd" to "Welcome" should mean changing "57 65 6c 63 6f 6d 64 0d 0a" to "57 65 6c 63 6f 6d 65 0d 0a"

Can you be more specific about

> Changing the text editor does not work for me

?

Answer (score 1):

Use `put_many_bytes`  function. 
(I think its from `idc` but I'm not sure